# Age Filter slider IOS

Tags: ios, filter, slider

I want to achieve something like this in my IOS app.

[image]

Is there any component available on Github for the same?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Searching for "ios range slider" returns many potentially useful results. Can you ask a more specific question?

Comment: What could be more specific? I have already attached an image what is my requirement, And i have been trying Slider control but cant get the correct Output.

Answer (score 1):

try [NMRangeSlider](https://github.com/muZZkat/NMRangeSlider) It has got two ranges edges suitable for your age range slider

Answer (score 0):

You can not get exact slider according to your needs. There are many slider controls available, but you have to make some modification to accomplish your needs.

Here some example of Slider Control :

1. [TTRangeSlider](https://github.com/TomThorpe/TTRangeSlider)
2. [MARKRangeSlider](https://github.com/vadymmarkov/MARKRangeSlider)
3. [NMRangeSlider](https://github.com/muZZkat/NMRangeSlider)
4. [ACVRangeSelector](https://github.com/tapsandswipes/ACVRangeSelector)
5. [VPRangeSlider](https://github.com/varunpm1/VPRangeSlider)